# bash condition expansion as in C

Tags: bash, boolean, conditional-statements

Is there any solution in bash to this C (and some other language) "function"?

```
condition ? true_value : false_value
```

Only need a simple check: if a variable is 0, return a value else return an other value.

**EDIT**
Thanks for answers but I want a similar:

```
./configure ${want_foo=1 ? --enable-foo : --disable-foo}
```

Is it possible or any workaround?

Comment: @mvp please check my edit! I think I wasn't exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't have the `C` style `ternary operator`. But you can simulate it like

```
[[ condition ]] && true_value || false_value
```

As per updated question:

```
./configure $( [[ want_foo == 1 ]] && echo --enable-foo || echo --disable-foo )
```

Comment: It works, but need a some edit: ${want_foo} should be in condition, and == instead of =.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The idiom I usually use is:

```
condition && echo yes || echo no
```

`condition` can be, for example, a test expression:

```
b=$( (( a == 0 )) && echo A_VALUE || echo AN_OTHER_VALUE )
```

Or, as in your revised question:

```
./configure $( (( want_foo == 1 )) && echo --enable-foo  || echo --disable-foo )
```

Just to be clear, you can use `?:` directly in arithmetic expressions. You only need the above if you want to use strings.